# Bootstrap `justify-content-center` isn't centering without explicit column number

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have:

```
<div id="root" class="container-fluid">
    <div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <form>
```

and the form (which is small widthwise) is not centering. If I add a number to the `col` div (ie. `col-4`) then the small column will be centered but the form left-justified within it and starts wrapping weirdly in a small viewport. Moving the `justify-...` part to the `col` didn't do anything either.

How am I supposed to go about centering that form element?

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the `form-inline` class on the form and put the `justify-content` class on the form as well. the justify class didn't need to go anywhere else.

Comment: You should be able to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: You can't mark your own answer as correct for at least 48hrs after you post. Very dumb IMO but I have to wait still